# how to add a context name which we give in schema while importing data from a csv file via mlcp

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I want to add the context name right now on pushing the data while exploring the document I get is this:-

```
{{
    "key1": "test1",
    "key2": "test2",
    "key3": "test3",
    "key4": "test4."
}}
```

where else I want is This:-

```
{
  "RouterAnomalyData":{
    "key1": "test1",
    "key2": "test2",
    "key3": "test3",
    "key4": "test4."
  }
}
```

please advise??

Comment: Please provide a small sample data file and the MLCP options that you have tried -- that makes it easier for us to make suggestions about what to change.

Answer (score 0):

I had hoped that the `-delimited_root_name` option would do what you need, but that only works for XML. I have filed [a request on GitHub](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-contentpump/issues/66) to add that feature. In the meantime, you'll need to use an MLCP transform. See [Transforming Input During Ingestion](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_82518). Your function will look something like this:

```
function yourTransform(content, context)
{
  // content.value is a document node. Convert to an object 
  // and wrap it with the new property. 
  const newDoc = {
     "RouterAnomalyData": content.value.toObject()
  }

  // Update the content with the new document. 
  content.value = xdmp.unquote(xdmp.quote(newDoc));

  return content;
}
```

You can then [install the transform](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_90588) and [call the transform during ingest](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_36783). That should result in the structure you're looking for.